# Download All the files from s3 for specific date onwards using python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

i am trying to improve my current code which is download file from s3 to local machine.what i need to do is, lets say yesterday i have downloaded the files from s3 but today i forgot to download the files. then when i am going to download files from s3 today it should download the yesterday and today files.basically it should download all files from last downloaded date to current date.so how i am suppose to do this?

my code is:

visit: [How to download Amazon S3 files on to local machine in folder using python and boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979867/how-to-download-amazon-s3-files-on-to-local-machine-in-folder-using-python-and-b)

Comment: You should record the last download date or time to somewhere.

Comment: If you are running this locally it might be better to use awscli to sync a local folder with your remote bucket. This will download only the files you don't already have. If you insist on using your own code, store the timestamp in a file and next time you run your code extract the timestamp to use it in your if condition and also update it and store it again

Comment: thank you @NinadGaikwad.I have already implemented code that way